# Changing numbers in a file, cannot use .split

Tags: python, string, file, loops, io

```
def process_body(infile, outfile, modification):
    '''
    changing the numbers to the outfile              
    '''


for line in infile.readline():
    line = line.strip()
    input()
    num = ""
    for char in line: 
        if modification == "negate": 
            if char != " ":
                #concatenate "digits"
                num += char
            else:
                #convert already concatenated "digits"
                negate_line = negate(num)
                print(negate_line)
                #clear for next number
                num = ""
```

Here is my negate function

```
def negate(num):
    '''
    absolute value of RGB value - 255
    '''

    num = int(num)
    negate_line = abs(num - 255)
    negate_line_out = str(negate_line)
    return negate_line_out
```

This is code that should read in numbers from a file and subtract 255 and print to the outfile. I am not allowed to use `split`. Here is some code from the infile

```
0 44 89 0 44 89 0 44 89 0 44 89 1 45 90 
1 45 90 1 45 90 1 45 90 1 45 92 1 45 92
1 55 101 0 54 100 0 54 100 0 53 99 0 53 99 
0 54 101 0 54 101 0 54 101 0 54 101 0 54 101 
0 54 101 0 54 101 0 54 101 0 53 103 0 53 103
```

Right now my error is 
these are the numbers I am getting returned

```
255  251  246  255  251  246  255  251  246  255  251  246  254  250
```

But these are the numbers I need

```
255 211 166 255 211 166 255 211 166 255 211 166 254 210 165
```

Is there a reason the numbers are processing incorrectly?

Comment: I saw this numbers yesterday - somebody already ask for this problem.

Comment: Error means you try to convert space `" "` into integer. But I don't see `int()` in your code.

Comment: Yeah it was probably me, still trying to make it work, this is the most updated code. But the other threads died

Comment: @sarahcampolt Did your previous question that has answers address those problems you originally had? Because there are upvotes on those answers and you didn't accept an answer yet.

Comment: @furas I added my function that applied the int()

Comment: @idjaw they did not address the problems. I'm pretty new to the website, I did not know I could accept an answer

Comment: now you know what problem is - you have to check if `num` is not `" "` before you try `int()` and rest in `negate()`

Comment: @sarahcampolt When you look at the answers, you will see a greyed out checkmark to the left of the answer. That is the accept. You can only accept one answer per question.

Comment: this is wrong: `elif char == " ": negate_line = negate(char)`. You call `negate()` only with space `" "` I think you need another varaible to keep string with digits, not `char` variable.

Comment: @idjaw I updated my code and here is the new problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep (concatenated) digits/number in different variable than `char` and use `negate` with this variable when `char` is `" "`

```
data = '''0 44 89 0 44 89 0 44 89 0 44 89 1 45 90 
1 45 90 1 45 90 1 45 90 1 45 92 1 45 92
1 55 101 0 54 100 0 54 100 0 53 99 0 53 99 
0 54 101 0 54 101 0 54 101 0 54 101 0 54 101 
0 54 101 0 54 101 0 54 101 0 53 103 0 53 103 '''

modification = "negate"

#for line in infile:
for line in data.split('\n'):
    line = line.strip()

    # to keep concatenated "digits"
    num = ''

    for char in line: 
        if char != " ":
            # concatenate "digits"
            num += char
        else:
            if modification == "negate": 
                # convert already concatenated "digits"
                negate_line = negate(num)
                print(negate_line, end=" ")
                # clear for next number
                num = ''

    # last number - because there is no " " after this number
    if num:
        if modification == "negate": 
            negate_line = negate(num)
            print(negate_line, end=' ')
            # clear for next number
            num = ''

    print()

def negate(num):
    num = int(num)
    negate_line = abs(num - 255)
    negate_line_out = str(negate_line)
    return negate_line_out
```

Comment: When I use your code my output is just blank spaces.

Comment: do you use exactly mu code or with your other code ? My code use data from string, not from file. You have to change `for` line.

Comment: I feel like your code is the correct answer, I have no idea why my output is just spaces.

Comment: check variables using `print()` - this way you can find problem. Maybe in `modification` you have text different than `"negate"`.

Comment: I did change the for line, I will edit my main question to show the code I have now that is just outputing spaces.

Comment: I have hard coded the modification as of now, would you like me to post my entire program?

Comment: why do you use `input()` ? Print `modification` or event `print(modification == "negate")`

Comment: I use input() so that the file only prints one line at a time in order to try and debug

Comment: btw; it should be `readlines()` with `s` at the end, or shorter `for line in infile:`

Comment: Version `for line in infile:` do the same as `for line in infile.readlines():` but is shorter, you can't make mistake with "s" - so it is more popular.

Comment: everything is working really well, except the last number in the file is not being negated. Is there a reason on the last number of the line would be excluded and a way to fix it?

Comment: it isn't negated because there is no " " after last number which normally execute `else:` :) I made modification in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can't use split? No problem! Write your own split:

```
import itertools

def splitNums(line, delim=' '):
    answer = []
    for k,group in itertools.groupby(line, lambda x: x==delim):
        if k: continue
        g = ''.join(group).strip()
        if not g.strip(): continue
        answer.append(int(g))

    return answer


def negateNumber(n):
    return abs(n-255)

def negateFile(infilepath, outfilepath):
    with open(infilepath) as infile, open(outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            nums = splitNums(line)
            negs = [negateNumber(n) for n in nums]
            outfile.write(' '.join([str(i) for i in negs]))
            outfile.write('\n')
```

With your input file, I get this output file:

```
255 211 166 255 211 166 255 211 166 255 211 166 254 210 165 
254 210 165 254 210 165 254 210 165 254 210 163 254 210 163 
254 200 154 255 201 155 255 201 155 255 202 156 255 202 156 
255 201 154 255 201 154 255 201 154 255 201 154 255 201 154 
255 201 154 255 201 154 255 201 154 255 202 152 255 202 152
```